# Simple network location test not working?

Tags: android

I just want to see what form the location is returned as from a coarse location fix. Using the google code as so:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_mission);


     // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
              makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
            }


            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
          };

        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    }


    private void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location) {

        TextView locationOutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationOutput);
        locationOutput.setText((CharSequence) location);

    }
```

This isn't working on my handset so I assume it isn't this easy. What am I missing?

TIA

Current permission enabled:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Have you edit Manifest.xml

Comment: Have you enabled wifi and network location in your device's settings?

Comment: Yes I've added the COARSE location to the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add permission in the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Also you can get locations which are null, make sure to be able to handle it.

**Edit**

Try `getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` or add permission to wifi.

Comment: I've allowed coarse but not fine.